How to make a search bar using HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT that works
First time doing this, I have gone through several tutorials. I don't understand why the Javascript is not working or showing up on the DOM. Here are a few of the search functions~
I added an event listener, a function that identifies if the search value matches the blog title, and if it does it is supposed to show up on a separate web page.
Example 1
document.addEventListener('click', searchResult); 

function searchResult() {
let input = document.getElementById('search-i').value;
input = input.toLowerCase();
let blogName = document.getElementsByClassName('.blog-title');

for (let i = 0; i < blogName.length; i++) {
if (!blogName[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
  document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = 'no results';
}
else {
  document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML.blogName[i] = blogName[i];
}
}
};

Example 2
function searchResult() {
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-i').value;
const blogTitle = document.querySelector('.blog-title');
const search = search-i.value.toLowerCase();

blogTitle.forEach((blogTitle) => {
const itemMatchesSearch = searchResult(blogTitle, search);

if (itemMatchesSearch)
document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = `${blogTitle}`;
style.display = 'block';

} else {
document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = 'no items found';
style.display = 'block';
});
}

searchResult();

Example 3
function searchResult() {
const input = document.getElementById('search-i').value;
input.toLowerCase();
const blogName = document.getElementsByClassName('.blog-title');

  for (let i = 0; i < blogName.length; i++) {
  if (blogName[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML;
    const displayResult = document.createElement('li');
    list.appendChild(displayResult);
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML.appendChild(displayResult) =            blogName[i];
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = 'no results found';
    style.display = block;
  }
}};



HTML


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Finance Blog</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-   awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<span class="header">
<h1>Finance Blog</h1>
</span>

    <div class="search-div">
      <form action="searchresults.html" method="get">
     <button type="submit" class="search-button" id="search-b" onclick="searchResult ()"><i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i></button>
      <input type="text" class="search" id="search-i" placeholder="search..." onclick="searchResult ()">
  </form>
    </div>

<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="deals.html" class="nav-bar" id="deals">Deals</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="free.html" class="nav-bar" id="free">Free</a>
  <li>
    <a href="savingmoney.html" class="nav-bar" id="savingmoney">Saving Money</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="investing.html" class="nav-bar" id="investing">Investing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="makemoney.html" class="nav-bar" id="makemoney">Make Money</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="recipies.html" class="nav-bar" id="recipes">Recipies</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  </header>

 <main>
 <section class="blog"> 

 <div class="blog-container">
  <div class="blog-img"><img>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><h2 class="blog-title" id="blog-title">FREE Workouts: My Favorite Fun         Youtube Workout Channel
  </h2>
  </a>
  <p class="blog-copy"></p>
  <span class="time"></span>
</div>

<div class="blog-container">
  <div class="blog-img"><img>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><h2 class="blog-title" id="blog-title">How to Get FREE Coffee Grounds    from Starbucks for Your Garden!
  </h2>
  </a>
  <p class="blog-copy"></p>
  <span class="time"></span>
</div>

<div class="blog-container">
  <div class="blog-img"><img>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><h2 class="blog-title" id="blog-title">My Favorite Simple and Easy Credit Card 
  </h2>
  </a>
  <p class="blog-copy"></p>
  <span class="time"></span>
</div>

</section>


<div class="sidebar">
<aside>
<div><img src="pig.image" alt="pig photo" class="aside-img"/></div>

<br>

<div>
  <p class="aside-p">Sign up to never miss a post!</p>
  <br>
  <form>
  <input type="email" class="aside-input" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS">
  <br>
  <button class="button-submit">SIGN UP</button>
  </form>
</div>

<br>

<div class="social">
<a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-tiktok"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</div>


</aside>
</div>
</main>


<div class="container-pagination">
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="pagination-previous">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="pagination-next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </div>


<footer>
<div class="social-footer">
<a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-tiktok"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<p><a href="about.html" class="footer-p" id="about">About</a></p>
<br>
<p><a href="contact.html" class="footer-p" id="contact">Contact</a></p>
<br>
<p><a href="privacy.html" class="footer-p" id="privacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
<br>
<p><a href="terms.html" class="footer-p" id="terms">Terms</a></p>
</div>

<p class="footer-copyright" id="date"></p>
</footer>

<script src="js.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

CSS
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html body { 
overflow: auto; 
height: 100%;
}


body {
height: 100%;
}

header {
display: flex;
}


h1 {
color: #FB6F92;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.search-div {
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
display: flex;
}

.search-button {
color:#FB6F92;
margin: 5px;
border: none;
background: none;
padding: 0;

}

.search {
position: relative;
border-color:#FB6F92;
width: 250px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 25px;
font-size: 16px;
}

nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #fbe5e5;
font-family: arial;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
 }

nav a {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
color: #FB6F92;
text-decoration: none;
}

li {
display: inline;
margin: 20px;
}

.nav-bar:hover {
color: gray;
}

main {
display: flex;
 }

.blog {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 80%;
}

.blog-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
grid-auto-rows: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 25%;
margin: 15px;
  }

.blog-title {
color: black;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-size: 20px;
overflow: wrap;
}

.blog-container a {
text-decoration: none;
 }

.blog-img {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

.next-page {
font-family: Arial;
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
 }

.next-page a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar {
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 35px;
z-index: -100;
}

aside {
color: black;
font-family: arial;
position: sticky;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
overflow: auto;
  }

.aside-img {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 9px;
 }

.aside-p {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;

}

.aside-input {
margin-bottom: 5px;
width: 209px;
color: black;
border-style: solid;
padding: 5px;
border-color: black;
font-size: 13px;
}

.aside-span {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 22px;
}

.button-submit {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 6px;
color:#FB6F92;
background-color: #fbe5e5;
width: 223px;
border-style: none;

}

.social a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
 }


.container-pagination {
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

.container-pagination a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 }


footer {
width: 100%;
height: 170px;
bottom: 0px;
font-family: arial;
background-color: #fbe5e5;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
padding-bottom: 70px;

}
.social-footer {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;

}
.social-footer a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;

}
.footer-content {
grid: 2/4fr;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 70px;

}
.footer-copyright {
width: 100%;
bottom: -200px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
font-size: 14px;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 25px;

}
.footer-p {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;

}
I attempted to create functions and put them in the DOM.

Are you trying to have in page js change the content of an external page? Or just filter results on the current page?

I created a second page for the results. I wanted to filter though the results on the index page, and then put them on the second page. The js is all on one page.

You could pass a query string in the url and have the second page filter content, and the second page has all content by default. The alternative is to have a server which gives a different response depending on what your request looks like. Does that make sense? Each page is self contained, and allows for very specific channels to communicate with others.

maybe you could use some form of local storage or something to keep information between the two pages.

I was going to make a runnable snippet of your code, but I decided against it, since that would require a fixup of your original code, and it would, perhaps, eliminate the problem you're facing. Your HTML is missing a lot of closing (missing </li>) and opening tags (stray </h2> without its opening pair). Please, use a validator of any kind (for example, this). Your Javascript code is also missing some closing curly braces and brackets. Please recheck your code, and check your console for errors.

If your goal is to pass information along from your index page to a search page, it should probably look something like this.
Index Page:
<input id="search-input" /><a id="search-button" href="/search.html?">search</a>
<script>
    const get = (query, dom = document) => [...dom.querySelectorAll(query)];

    const searchButton = get("#search-button")[0];
    const searchInput = get("#search-input")[0];
    searchInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
        const searchQuery =  searchInput.value;
        searchButton.href = "/search.html?query=" + encodeURIComponent(searchQuery);
    });
</script>

This will allow you to type into the input, and when you hit the search button, it will take you to the search page with the query string attached.
Search Page:
<h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
<div class="post">Post 0</div>
<div class="post">Post 1</div>
<div class="post">Post 2</div>
<div class="post">Post 3</div>
<div class="post">Post 4</div>
<script>
    const get = (query, dom = document) => [...dom.querySelectorAll(query)];

    filterFromQueryString: {
        const href = window.location.href;
        const queryString = href.split("?")[1];
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const query = searchParams.get("query");
        if (!query) break filterFromQueryString;
        get(".post").forEach(post => {
            // this just searches all text content
            // and hides if no match
            // you could also add tags to the post data
            // or only search the post body or something
            const postText = post.textContent;
            const textLowercase = postText?.toLowerCase();
            const containsQuery = textLowercase.includes(query);
            if (containsQuery) return;
            post.style.display = "none";
        });
    }
</script>

This will grab the search query from the url query string, and hide posts that don't match the query string.

thank you, I am still trying to get it to work
